# Cannot escape a path in a custom TFS Build Template

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a c# project for maintaining my custom build templates that are derived from the default template in TFS 2012.

I have paths that one of my template files that appropriately show an unrecognizable escape sequence when path is in the form of `\\machine\c$\path`

However, when I add `@` to the beginning of this path `@"\\machine\c$\path"`, I get a compilation error.

I checked the file in xml editor and I do have a csharp reference included.

Any advice?

Comment: Compile errors encountered processing expression. What is interesting, is that the designer has a value of New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TestSpecList(New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.AgileTestPlatformSpec(@"**\*test*.dll")) for the argument TestSpecs. This is vb code. If the template is vb, why would it complain about escape sequence characters?

Comment: In further review, the empty arguments on the template have a watermark of "Enter a VB expression".

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly altered the build action on the template to "Compile" and not "XamlAppDef". When I changed to XamlAppDef, the template built normally.